# В чем заключается ошибка текста? dbForge mysql

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
FUNCTION football.func_4(T_id integer(10))
  RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE N float;
SELECT AVG(M) INTO N
  FROM (SELECT MIN(goals.Goal_time) AS M
    FROM teams, games, goals
  WHERE (games.Game_id=goals.Game_id
  AND teams.Team_id=games.Team_1_id   
  AND teams.Team_id=T_id) 
  OR (games.Game_id=goals.Game_id
  AND  teams.Team_id=games.Team_2_id 
  AND teams.Team_id=T_id)
  GROUP BY goals.goal_id);
RETURN N;
END
```

Говорит об ошибке в тексте и не может сохранить

Comment: *Говорит об ошибке в тексте* Извольте процитировать всё, вплоть до запятых и переводов строк.

Comment: 1 Невозможно перейти на страницу дизайнера. Объект имеет неверный исходный текст. Function:football.function1(MySQL)

Comment: Все претензии - к dbForge, это его сообщение, а не MySQL-сервера. По этому "сочинению на тему" ничего сказать нельзя. Рекомендация: выполнить создание функции на консоли сервера. PS. Следи, чтобы сообщение об ошибке (в котором *function1*) соответствовало тексту вопроса (а там - *func_4*).

Comment: сейчас посмотрим

Comment: Ну и в порядке вангования - DELIMITER не забыл?

Comment: в консоли выдал ошибку Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @Ренат Вы делаете select из подзапроса, все подзапросы в MySQL должны иметь имена `select avg() from (....) X`

Comment: После     завершения написания условий поставил as C, все заработало, исправил тип возвращаемого значени на time.  Возвратил ошибку Data truncated for column 'football.func_4(2)' at row 16